# Xcode is not seeing addition to cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Added a new class and methods to the existing code in an imported pod.

I checked everything I could in the Utilities for this new class.

- Location of .h and .m file is selected as 'Relative to project' like all other files in this pod
- actual files are in the same path as the other file of this pod
- target membership is same as pod.

Xcode is not seeing the addition of the new class (h file in an import statement in the project using the pod).

Comment: What do you mean by 'Xcode is not seeing' the files? Do you get compiler errors (which have nothing to do with Xcode, by the way)?

Comment: yeah "MyClass.h" file not found.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it doesn’t work for you, but aside from that you should **not** modify the Pods.xcodeproj. CocoaPods assumes it has control over it and will wipe out your changes on the next `pod install` or `pod update`. (Maybe that’s the problem your seeing?)

Either add the custom class to your own project, extend the library with categories in your own project, or have a fork of the library where you push your changes to (possibly by using the `:local` directive in your Podfile).